# Django-polymorphic - can I specify order by content type?

Tags: python, django, django-polymorphic

I use `django-polymorphic` for multiple product types.

```
class Product(PolymorphicModel):
    order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=999, verbose_name='Poradie')

class WoodProduct(Product):
    ....

class IronProduct(Product):
    ....

class PlasticProduct(Product):
    ....
```

I want to set default ordering (or explicitly specify when filtering `QuerySet`) based on

```
1. model type 
2. order attribute
```

The closest I got is to set `ordering = ['polymorphic_ctype_id']` in the `class Meta` of `Product` model.

So now I have grouped products by model type but I can't set, which type will be the first,second etc...

How can I ensure that `Product.objects.all()` will return `QuerySet` with ordering - `WoodProduct`s , `PlasticProduct`s, `IronProduct`s ?

**EDIT**

So it would look like:

```
class Product(...):
   class Meta:
       ordering = [(WoodProduct,PlasticProduct,IronProduct),'order']
```

Comment: may be this can help you https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced.html#combining-querysets

Comment: Is the EDIT an answer?  Does this work (aren't WoodProduct, PlasticProduct, and IronProduct undefined when defining Product?

Answer (score 1):

I can't to test. But based on the docs [iltering-inherited-classes](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced.html#polymorphic-filtering-for-fields-in-inherited-classes) and [combining-querysets](https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced.html#combining-querysets) the solution can be:

```py
query = Product.objects.instance_of(WoodProduct).order_by('order')
query |= Product.objects.instance_of(PlasticProduct).order_by('order')
query |= Product.objects.instance_of(IronProduct).order_by('order')
```

Comment: BearBrown - that seems reasonable, thank you. I've just solved it another way but I appreciate this solution, I had to add new attribute `product_type_order`.